# different project for celery task code, and calling

Tags: celery

I have a python project where I create this function:

```
celeryApp = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://...')


@celeryApp.task
def do_stuff(in):
    return in*5
```

I want to call add it from another project, without sharing the file name.

How do i do it using the shared_task ? I don't understand where I put the the shared_task, is it in the worker or in the app ?

Comment: maybe this could help you. https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/06/19/call-celery-task-outside-codebase/